# Jetty 9 embedded mode without web.xml and war file

Tags: java, jetty

I have used Jetty 8 in its embedded mode to develop a web application without a web.xml and a war file. However I don't really know how to do the same in Jetty 9. It seems that some things have changed in from Jetty 8 to Jetty9. Can someone point me to waht to do?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you give some examples of what you were doing in jetty 8 and what you think isn't working in jetty 9?

Answer (score 1):

Little has changed in that regard, the primary changes between jetty 8 and jetty 9 were in the underlying IO layers.

There are many embedded examples here:

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded

And the documentation here:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html